# How to access children elements of <nav>

Tags: angularjs

I want to access children `li` elements of `nav`. but its display undefine.

```
  <nav>
                <ul class="info-section">
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="basicInfo">Basic Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="extInfo">Extended Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="loanSize">Loan Size / LVR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="loanFees">Loan Fees</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="services">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

I am using bello code in cutome directive

```
     nav = angular.element(document.querySelector(".info-section"));
```

its returning dom element. but if I write bellow line. its prints `undefine`

```
  console.log(nav.children[0].classList);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? Is this inside a controller or a service?

Comment: inside custome directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access the `0` position of the element

`nav[0].children[0].classList`

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

var nav = angular.element(document.querySelector(".info-section"));
console.log(nav[0].children[0].classList)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <nav>
                <ul class="info-section">
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="basicInfo">Basic Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="extInfo">Extended Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="loanSize">Loan Size / LVR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="loanFees">Loan Fees</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="services">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this. There is no direct method to get the children of element

```
nav = angular.element(document.querySelector(".info-section"));
nav[0].getElementsByTagName('li')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have zero knowledge on angular, but you can try this

```js
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav");
var ulWithInfoSection = nav[0].getElementsByClassName("info-section")[0];
console.log(ulWithInfoSection.getElementsByTagName("li"));
```

```html
 <nav>
                <ul class="info-section">
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="basicInfo">Basic Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="extInfo">Extended Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="loanSize">Loan Size / LVR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="loanFees">Loan Fees</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="services">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```